# Mule expression language boolean

Tags: mule, mvel

I have an enricher which invokes a method and returns true or false. However, when I test the condition it doesn't trigger the action. The documentation says that testing with keyword 'empty' returns true if the value in the expression returns false. When the checkExisting returns false, I expect the Action to be triggered but that does not happen.  What is the problem?

```
<enricher target="#[variable:myVal]">
  <invoke object-ref="myBean" method="checkExisting" methodArguments="#
                                                               [payload]"/>
</enricher>

I check the result like this
   <choice>
     <when expression="#[myVal==empty]" >
      ... Action to take..
```

Answer (score 0):

The boolean check using MEL is considered in various places when using choice we need to explicitly check for values that needs to be satisfied.
I have tried checking for boolean value in filter Giving below the that I could succeed in having below MEL in filter expression. 
flowVars.FilterVar==true